# Solenoids and Permanent magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

Permanent magnets shows magnetic properties due to arrangement of domains in it.
Now when we bring a strong magnet [Assume $B=1\mathrm{T(tesla)}$] near  a weak magnet [(Assume $B=0.0025\mathrm{T(tesla)}$],Strong magnet will rearrange the domains in weak magnet and will attract both the poles of weak magnet.

Now similarly,
If we have two Air-core Solenoids with same geometrical measurements (length of coil,area of coil,wire material,length of wire,radius of wire and number of turns).
My Question is.....
When we pass current in both the solenoids such that one of solenoid have B=1T and other have $B=0.0025\mathrm{T}$.
Will the solenoid withe $B=1\mathrm{T}$ attract both the poles of solenoid with $B=0.0025\mathrm{T}$ ?
If yes or No please give me the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want a theoretical explanation, the force between solenoids is the sum of forces between current loops, which [can be calculated](https://physicspages.com/pdf/Griffiths%20EM/Griffiths%20Problems%2005.49.pdf).

I think it is more complicated to precisely explain the behavior of permanent magnets.